# Calculating effective APR of a mortgage

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, apr

I am trying to reproduce in Google Docs the calculations underlying the sample mortgage Closing Disclosure provided by the CFPB at:

http://files.consumerfinance.gov/f/201311_cfpb_kbyo_closing-disclosure.pdf

That document describes a mortgage with the following parameters:

`Loan Amount:           $162000
Annual Interest Rate:   3.875%
monthly PMI:            $82.35
total loan costs:     $4694.05
prepaid interest:      $279.04`

and summarizes it as follows (page 5):

`Total Payments:     $285803.36
Finance Charge:     $118830.27
Amount Financed:    $162000.00
Annual Percent Rate:    4.174%
Total Interest Percent: 69.46%`

Almost everything I calculate seems to agree but I can't get the formula right for the effective APR (4th line of summary).

I currently calculate it as follows

`=100*12*rate(12*30, -1*(4694.05+279.04+162000+-1*cumipmt(0.03875/12, 30*12, 162000, 1, 30*12, 0)+82.35*80)/360, 162000, 0, 0)`

This comes out to 4.218%, not 4.174% as published.

What am I missing?

The code I'm using is here:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VQshp3A55brVv17eS9REdBjBUG0EmwTrcwhgXBVK8m8/edit#gid=0

Comment: Questions asked here must contain all relevant content here, not at another site. See [ask] and [mcve]. If the relevant content is located off-site, and that off-site location is unavailable (moved, deleted, etc.), the question has no value for future readers. As currently written, there is no relevant content here. (In addition, *My code won't work. Figure out why* is far from being a *specific question*.)

Comment: Hi Ken White, part of the scope of my question is to determine which subset of the numbers provided in the first link are relevant.  I certainly could list all of them, but that does not seem minimal.  I would upvote a response that gave me a clue as to which numbers my code has ignored are in fact relevant.  To address your comment I have included all inputs to my calculation that I would expect to be relevant.  But I may be wrong -- and that is exactly my question.  Thanks for making my question clearer.

Answer (score 0):

APR has many nuances. It's primarily a customer-facing metric, so banks feel pressured to keep the number low.

Many institutions assume 12 months of 30 days each; some take other approaches. There's different ways of treating leap years, Escrow, etc.. Since you are close, but not exact, likely this institution has a non-standard APR calculation.

Comment: The institution is the Consumer Financial Protection Bureau, I think they are supposed to publish the standard APR calculation, whatever that is.